# Jmeter If controller not executing with Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, jsr223, jmeter-5.0

Following is my test plan. Where If controller should execute when user defined variable "userTaskIds" size is greater than zero which is set in previous request.

[image]

[image]

If controller not executing even though userTaskIds size is greater than zero. If block should execute when previous request is success and userTaskIds >0.

```
(${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}) && (${__groovy(vars.get("userTaskIds").size() > 0 )})
```

ForEach controller
[image]
Following is the debug sampler output
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that works should be:

> ${__groovy(vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok")=="true" && (vars.getObject("userTaskIds").size() > 0 ),)}

Note it's even better to use [__jexl3](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function:

> ${__jexl3(vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok")=="true" && (vars.getObject("userTaskIds").size() > 0 ),)}

Comment: Now if block executing fine, however ForEach loop not executing with userTaskIds variable. added screen shot in main thread.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, open a new question with details on second problem, I’ll be happy to help.